# Software producing complex trees

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-software

Does anyone know any kind of graph software that could produce graphs like this for publication? Those links and crosses and numbers actually needs to be presented…. Thank you:)

One small update, those 0,1s will be replaced by pictures:)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "produce"? Are you willing to lay this out by hand? If so, the LaTeX package xypic would be one workable solution. Or do you need a range of them, produced with some amount of automation?

Comment: Oh... Actually, what I mean by produce is simply that I could draw it out... I just need one such graph actually, thank you soo much.

Comment: Scanning is your friend.

Comment: Do you mean I simply scan????:)

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. Scan, then include the result as a figure.

Comment: This will take you essentially 0 time compared to the high-tech mentods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tikz](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) can do what you wish, if you don't mind writing LaTeX(-like) code to produce them. If you are familiar with LaTeX, it's worth your time to go through its learning curve in my opinion; it can access all of TeX's rendering capabilities natively and hence produce graphs that blend perfectly with the text style.

If you want a point-and-click graphic interface, I can suggest something like Inkscape or Dia.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica has a [TreePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreePlot.html) function, and a [LayeredGraphPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LayeredGraphPlot.html),
and you can replace the nodes with whatever graphical object or picture you want (even other graphs if you like, which I have found useful).

Answer (score 1):

I once used [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and I think it should do what you want quite well.   Essentially you edit a text file with a fairly straight forward format, and then run some compiler on it to produce the figure.

[image]